# How to merge packages with same name but different modules present in seprate git repos in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, module, package

So, my use case has
for eg different git repos like repo1, repo2, repo3 with a structure like

```
repo1 ->

      ->same_package_name
        ->moduleA
        ->moduleB
repo2 ->

      ->same_package_name
         ->moduleC
         ->moduleD

repo3 ->

   ->same_package_name
     ->moduleE
```

Now if i want to use modueleA, moduleC I will do something like :

```
pip install git+repo1 
pip install git+repo2
```

but since the **package_name is same** in different repositories which is a requirement, it replaces the second pip install. i,e i will see package name -> module C and not module A.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort.  Please provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Packages should never have the same name in Python since Python doesn't support that. If both packages had the same method name as well, how would it know which one you were referring to?

Comment: This is not possible with the pip. All of the packages on PyPI have unique names. Packages often require and depend on each other, and assume the name will not change. Even if you manage to put the code on Python path, when importing a module, python searches the paths in sys.path by order and stops at first match. So whatever module it finds first, it'll stop at that. 

You best bet is to copy all the code from the libraries to you codebase, change the module name of either and then import it.

Reference :- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-Install-two-python-modules-with-same-name